# How to get time zone of the client

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html

I want to access ***timezoneId*** of client. For this I had tried different approaches to get timezoneId information. Like:

1. calculating timezone from offset & daylight saving time,
2. getting user location(i.e.longitude, latitude value) to know the timezoneId of that location

I am getting the result but exact results (for all timezones) For example two countries having same offset value then I am unable to locate exact one based on their system timezone setting; like:*for Arizona and Mountain Time(US & Canada) both having offset value is UTC-7.00*

Right now for both the value it is giving "MST" i.e. Mountain Standard Time as timezoneId. But I want what ever I will configure means if I will select Arizona then it will return Arizona and if I will select Mountain Time(US & Canada) then it will give its corresponding timezoneId.

Can you help me to get exact timezoneId ?

Thanks,

Comment: check it out :) https://github.com/Canop/tzdetect.js. The implementation is in moment.js

Comment: i have tried this, it is giving not exact one for example Matching if i tried to access http://dystroy.org/stackoverflow/timezonedetect.html i got like this timezones :
Asia/Calcutta
Asia/Colombo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is small lib jsTimezoneDetect. It should give you America/Arizona, etc.

> http://pellepim.bitbucket.org/jstz/

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.toString();
//This will give you like MST, according to browser's time
var timeZone = (n.split("(")[1]).replace(")", "");
```